# Add ignore tag button to tag info dialog

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

I believe ignoring tags is a powerful tool to discover appropriate question to answer. So, it will be easier to ignore tag from the info dialog itself, Otherwise, I have to go to my site settings preference to add ignore tag.

[image]